# Can you use ZendGuard to encode only part of a website?

Tags: php, zend-guard

I am creating a website which I would like to protect using ZendGuard but I do not want to encode the entire website. Is it possible to only encode the core of the website and leave specific modules editable?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is an "Exclude List" in the configure for every project in Zend Guard, you can add any files and folders which you do not want to encrypt into the list, so the Zend Guard will ignore them when encrypting.